# Why does 'pod update' produce 'stty: stdin isn't a terminal' on Hudson?

Tags: ios, terminal, continuous-integration, hudson, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods and calling 'pod update' in the my job's build step on our Hudson server.

Here is the log:

```
+ pod update
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories
stty: stdin isn't a terminal
...
```

I don't get this when working directly from the command line on my machine or working directly on the Hudson machine. What's going on and should I be concerned?

Comment: Possibly useful https://github.com/cppforlife/checkman/issues/6 this seems to be some issue with readline/terminal configuration